# How to donwload Android SDK separatly?

Tags: android, installation

I have a small problem I believe, well I download androidstudio exe file, then started downloading, and I had a disk of only about 2G, so I clicked to download the sdk and started downloaing but stopped because of space problem, so I uninstalled android studio, increased my disk space, and then started re downloading, android studio is installed now, but SDK option did not pop up to download it, how Can I do so ?

Answer (score 0):

To answer your first question, yes you can download SDK toold

https://developer.android.com/studio#command-tools

To answer your size related question

You can skip `image` file download to save space, but you need your mobile device connected via USB

To answer you `SDK Manager` Question, Click this menu

Tools -> SDK Manager

Then you can specify the location of SDK or download individual APIs

Answer (score 0):

**Here's your guide:**

1. Go to https://developer.android.com/studio
2. Download Android Studio
3. Start Android Studio
4. You will be asked where to install the latest SDK
5. Wait till download is complete
6. Start Android Studio
7. Go to File > Settings > Appearance & Behaviour > System Settings > Android SDK
8. The latest SDk version (Android 10.0 at time of this post) should be marked with a check mark
9. Check any Android version you want to install (I suggest 4.1 and/or 5.0)
10. start developing